# Android Launcher3 build fails

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I'm trying to build the Android Launcher3 App I cloned from 
"git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher".

I imported it in Android Studio (2.1.1) but it doesn't build the project, and throws following error. It looks like some protobuf related issue but I couldn't figure out after several hours on google. Any help would be appreciated.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  ```
  Execution failed for task ':generateDebugProto'.
  > protoc: stdout: . stderr: C:\Launcher3\src\main\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\build\extracted-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\build\extracted-include-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\src\debug\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\build\extracted-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\build\extracted-include-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\src\debug\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\build\extracted-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
  C:\Launcher3\build\extracted-include-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
  backup.proto:21:8: Option "javanano_use_deprecated_package" unknown.
  ```

  - Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 2.053 secs

Comment: I have the same problem. Goog luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use the latest code which has removed the line in `backup.proto`

`option javanano_use_deprecated_package = true;`

Then if your gradle's version is above `2.12` which can cause a breakage, you should change

`classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.0'`

to

`classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.7'`

in `build.gradle`, according to [This](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/v0.7.6)

Update on `2016.11.9`